# How to set the model in a viewmodel (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an `HelloWorldWPFApplication` class with the following method:

```
public override void Run()
{
    var app = new System.Windows.Application();
    app.Run(new ApplicationShellView());
}
```

The `ApplicationShellView` has the following XAML:

```
<winbase:ApplicationShell x:Class="HelloWorldWPFApplication.View.ApplicationShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:winbase="clr-namespace:Framework.Presentation.Control.Window;assembly=Framework"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:HelloWorldWPFApplication.ViewModel"
    Title="{Binding WindowTitle, Mode=OneWay}">

<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ApplicationShellViewModel  />
</Window.DataContext>

</winbase:ApplicationShell>
```

If my ViewModel (`ApplicationShellViewModel`) has the following method, the window will have the title set to "Test":

```
    public string WindowTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I want to set the title based on properties within the `HelloWorldWPFApplication` class.  I added the following to the HelloWorldWPFApplication's base class (which uses the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface):

```
private WpfApplicationBase<WpfApplicationDataBase> applicationModel;

public WpfApplicationBase<WpfApplicationDataBase> Application
{
    get { return this.applicationModel; }
    set { this.Set<WpfApplicationBase<WpfApplicationDataBase>>(ref this.applicationModel, value); }
}
```

So effectively, I plan on reusing the existing `HelloWorldWPFApplication` object as the model (in MVVM).

I changed the WindowTitle property as follows:

```
public string WindowTitle
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}",
              this.applicationModel.Data.FullName,
              this.applicationModel.Data.ReleaseVersion).Trim();
    }
}
```

Of course, at this stage my project creates a window without a title, as the application field has not been set.  I don't want to create a new application object within the view model as one already exists.  I want to use this existing object.  What is the best way to achieve this?

I am very new to MVVM/WPF - and from my basic understanding of MVVM I don't want to put any code-behind in the view.  I could have a static field set on a static class to the application object, and then assign this field in my view model (this works, but not sure having "global" variables is the best approach).

I have also tried creating the view model before showing the window, but have encountered a problem I have yet to solve.  In this implementation my run method appears as follows:

```
public override void Run()
{
    var window = new ApplicationShell();  // inherits from System.Windows.Window
    var vm = new ApplicationShellViewModel();
    vm.Application = this;  // this line won't compile
    window.DataContext = vm;

    this.Data.WpfApplication.Run(window);
}
```

I get a compile error:

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'HelloWorldWPFApplication.Program.HelloWorldApplication' to 'Framework.Business.Logic.Program.Application.WpfApplicationBase'

I'm confused with the error as my `HelloWorldWPFApplication` class inherits from `WpfApplicationBase`:

```
    public class HelloWorldApplication<T> : WpfApplicationBase<T>
    where T : HelloWorldApplicationData
```

Additionally, HelloWorldApplicationData inherits from WpfApplicationDataBase.

I get the pretty much the same problem with the following implementation:

```
public override void Run()
{
    var window = new ApplicationShell();
    var vm = new ApplicationShellViewModel();
    var app = new HelloWorldApplication<HelloWorldApplicationData>();
    vm.Application = app;  // Cannot implicitly convert type error again
    window.DataContext = vm;

    this.Data.WpfApplication.Run(window);
}
```

Exact error:

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'HelloWorldWPFApplication.Program.HelloWorldApplication' to 'Framework.Business.Logic.Program.Application.WpfApplicationBase'

Comment: So to clarify; `ApplicationShellViewModel` has an `Application` property which is an instance of `WpfApplicationBase<T>` which has a `WindowTitle` property?

Comment: ApplicationShellViewModel has the WindowTitle property, everything else you say is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the "Application" class in WPF should be used for one thing, and one thing only: *starting the program*. It is **not** a model.

That said, I would just pass everything in sequence (this can apply to a proper model as well):

```
MyViewModel viewmodel = new MyViewModel(this);
var app = new System.Windows.Application();
app.Run(new ApplicationShellView(viewmodel));
```

Of course, remove the data context set from XAML. This does require modifying your code behind to accept the VM object and set it to the DataContext in your constructor, but thats a standard way of passing the VM to the View.

You could also use a Service Locator to find your model, or a number of other ways. Unfortunately, its hard to say which one is right, since your model is so *weird*.

As a complete aside; the title of your program is very much a part of the View, and probably doesn't need to be bound at all (your name is static, so making your application class the model isn't buying you anything).

Comment: On the first point, yeah I understood this from the start.  My model is some app-specific data (at this point, the name of the app and the version number).  Sure the app name is static for a single project, but I am trying to automate the title and version number from the project's assembly properties (therefore will change depending on the concrete app and version built against my framework.dll).

Comment: @rasteve So have your view model (or actual model) go get it. I still wouldn't use "Application" as the model class. Regardless, the rest of my answer still holds; I was just trying to provide some general advice.

Comment: My HelloWorldWPFApplication class is a business logic class that handles some high level methods (run, shutdown etc).  It contains a Data property of type HelloWorldWPFApplicationData, which currently stores app-specific data.  2 of these properties are needed in my viewmodel to formulate a window title.  I'm not really sure if it is acceptable to reuse existing objects as a model in MVVM, or I should create a suitable model with the 2 properties.

Comment: @rasteve I might right a service class to get that data (whether it gets it dynamically or retrieves it from a pre-populated data structure. I would then have my model/view model use that class to get the info.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  MVVM/WPF is new to me so trying to build some sample progs to get my head around the concepts.  I also found this useful link whilst investigating the app.Run(new ApplicationShellView(viewmodel)); suggestion.  (http://paulstovell.com/blog/mvvm-instantiation-approaches)